# Process to get H4B VISA for USA get stamped

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, dependent-visa

I am working in USA with H1B VISA and my wife had H4B VISA. The stamped VISAs in our passports were expired an year ago. However our status got renewed while we were in USA and we got new i-797 documents. But our passport didn't get stamped with renewed status.

Now my wife is planning to visit our home country of India.

Now what should be the process to get new stamping for H4B VISA?

What are the documents that my wife has to carry for H4B VISA stamping?

Comment: Your visas didn't get renewed. Your status got renewed. Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

The status is your permission to be in the country.  The visa is your permission to enter the country.(a) You can't get a visa from inside the US. If you leave the country, you use the status renewal to get a new visa from the embassy in the country you are visiting.  That will involve an interview (the same as you had for the original H1B).

Depending on things like appointment times and wait times, this can be a little nerve wracking. You should check with your lawyer about the exact process (rather than believing a random stranger on the internet) - I suspect that because her visa is dependent on yours, it's you that needs to visit the embassy for the interview, etc.

I've done this to renew my own H1B, but my dependents just stayed in the US until we'd all got green cards.

(a) Not quite permission. Immigration can still turn you away.

Comment: You cannot get a visa in any "country you are visiting". Other than Canada or Mexico, no US consulate will handle cases of non-residents in the area of their jurisdiction.

Comment: Good point, thanks. (OP is visiting their home country though.)